# How do i keep validating string word length until it satisfies the condition?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, loops

So I have written this code to generate a random anime quote from the given website
could someone help me how can I make it so that the code checks if the quote has certain number of words and validates it accordingly

eg. If the quote has just 3 words I want it to try again
also if the quote has more than 20 words I want it to try again

I tried writing a while loop for it but it wasn't working any answers would be appreciated

```
url = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random"
data = requests.get(url).json()

anime = data["anime"]
quote =data["quote"]
character =data["character"]

print("Anime : "+anime)
print(quote)
print(" '"+character+"'")
```

the while loop solution i came up with

```
quote = ""
word_list = quote.split()
number = len(word_list)
while number<=3 and number>=15:
    url = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random"
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    anime = data["anime"]
    quote =data["quote"]
    character =data["character"]

    print("Anime : "+anime)
    print(quote)
    print(" '"+character+"'")
```

Comment: There are multiple problems with this: firstly number can't simultaneously be bigger  than 15 and less than 3, so your while loop is never accessed, secondly there is no modification of number within the while loop so when accessed (once you've changed the access condition) it will loop 5ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for (I'm assuming you wanted to stop on the first quote you found that was between 3 and 15 words long):

```
quote = ""
word_list = quote.split()
number = len(word_list)
while number<=3 or number>=15:
    url = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random"
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    anime = data["anime"]
    quote =data["quote"]
    character =data["character"]

    word_list = quote.split()
    number = len(word_list)

print("Anime : "+anime)
print(quote)
print(" '"+character+"'")
```

I only made a couple of changes to your original:

1. Your while loop needed a change from `and` to `or` (the length can never be both less than or equal to 3 and greater than or equal to 15, so the loop never got the chance to run)
2. You need to recalculate the value of `number` each time you get a new value from the API

Answer (score 0):

Your ***while*** loop needs to contain the ***or*** statement and the last condition should be ***number>=20***

```
while number<=3 or number>=20:
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer i also had to update the value of number in the while loop so it breaks eventually ```while number<=3 or number>=20:
    url = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random"
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    anime = data["anime"]
    quote =data["quote"]
    character =data["character"]

    print("Anime : "+anime)
    print(quote)
    print(" '"+character+"'")
    word_list = quote.split()
    number = len(word_list)
    print(number)```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind though that you don't update `number` in the loop block, so the condition will never change, even with the corrected `number<=3 or number>=20` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Finally This is the solution if someone needs the same thing

```
import requests
number = 0
while number<=3 or number>=30:
    url = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random"
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    anime = data["anime"]
    quote =data["quote"]
    character =data["character"]

    print("Anime : "+anime)
    print(quote)
    print(" '"+character+"'")
    word_list = quote.split()
    number = len(word_list)
    print(number)
```